# How to use `docker compose exec` with both grep and ANSI color?

Tags: django, linux, docker, tty, ansi-colors

I'm only casually familiar with Docker, and how TTYs work in Linux.  At work, I use commands like `docker compose up` to start the development stack (Postgres + Django), and `docker compose exec web python manage.py ...` to run Django commands during development.

Conflicting problems:

1. I can't pipe in input or grep output without adding `-T`.  I don't know why, I just know it works with it, and not without it.

   - I populate the DB with `docker compose exec -T db psql -U username myproj < snapshot.sql` because without the `-T` the input doesn't make it to psql.
   - I also add `-T` when I have to grep the output, like:
     `docker compose exec web python manage.py showmigrations | grep '[ ]'`.
2. However, when I use `-T`, it screws up ANSI coloring and formatting.

   - Without `-T`:
     [image]
   - With `-T`:
     [image]

Question:  What's the correct method?  How do I properly connect STDIN & STDOUT without messing up color & formatting?